# How to stop gitolite service

Tags: git, gitolite

I want to migrate gitolite to gerrit, so I have to stop the gitolite service before the migration. I want to run the command like this `service gitolite stop`, but it did't work! Can somebody tell me the right to do that? thx  :)

Comment: When you write `service gitolite stop`, can you see any warning/error/another text in your console?

Comment: it returns like this `ubuntu@local-git:~$ sudo service gitolite stop`
`gitolite: unrecognized service`

Answer (score 4):

If you are running a typical install of gitolite, there is no specific daemon running since it relies on pure ssh.  That's what makes gitolite magic. See [here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/overview/).  That's consistent with your error message.

So if you want to disable gitolite, you have 2 options.

The first one is to disable push only, still allowing read.  This is described [in this section](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/odds-and-ends/index.html).  This can be useful if you want to keep it as a pure read copy for historical reason/comparison with you gerrit.

The second one is simply to prevent any ssh command to succeed.  To do that, simply rename `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to something else (`~/.ssh/authorized_keys.removed` for example).  That should instantly prevent any git command to succeed on the server.  Of course, you **must** first find the user hosting your gitolite install. Do not do this on any other user as you may lock yourself out of your server.

I personally would go with the first solution.

In any case, I would strongly recommend getting familiar with the gitolite install/setup before doing that.  It's a quick read [here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/overview/#how-does-it-work) and [here for the install procedure.](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/quick_install/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer you could use [gitolite writable](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/odds-and-ends/index.html) to disable push. That can be done like this

If you created a separate user for gitolite switch to it first

```
sudo su GIT_USER
```

List usage

```
gitolite writable -h
```

List current status (exit code 0 for writable, 1 for not writable)

```
gitolite writable @all status

echo $?
```

Disable write on all repos

```
gitolite writable @all off
```